# What's the nearest equivalent of Beautiful Soup for Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, beautifulsoup

I love the Beautiful Soup scraping library in Python. It just works. Is there a close equivalent in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page from [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing) includes a chart of the relative popularity of various parsers.

Comment: Nice image.  Any possibility of finding it and uploading it to imgur?

Answer (score 11):

[Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/) is another HTML/XML parser. It's faster than hpricot according to [these benchmarks](http://gist.github.com/18533). Nokogiri uses libxml2 and is a drop in replacement for hpricot. It also has css3 selector support which is pretty nice.

Edit: There's a new benchmark comparing nokogiri, libxml-ruby, hpricot and rexml [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-xml-performance-benchmarks-1641.html).

[Ruby Toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) has a category on HTML parsers [here](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing.html).

Comment: Update for 2013: Hpricot's github page says it is no longer maintained and recommends Nokogiri instead.

Answer (score 5):

There's [scRUBYt!](https://github.com/scrubber/scrubyt),
[Rubyful-soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/RubyfulSoup/) (no longer maintained),
[WWW::Mechanize](http://rubyforge.org/projects/mechanize/),
[scrAPI](http://blog.labnotes.org/2006/07/11/scraping-with-style-scrapi-toolkit-for-ruby/) and a few more.

Or you could just use Hpricot or [Nokogiri](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/tree/master) for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

[Hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot)? I don't know what others are using...

Answer (score 0):

[mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) is not just a HTML parser so it is not in the [HTML parsing](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing) category of Rubytoolbox, but as a similar syntax to Beautiful Soup to find DOM elements [like links](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/main/GUIDE.rdoc#label-Finding+Links) and it also a multipurpose HTTP agent to automate a lot of web stuff.

```rb
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://google.com/')

page.links.each do |link|
  puts link.text
end
```